# How to disable default return key on UIKeyboardTypeDefault for UITextfiled when Text length is <=4

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboardtype

How to disable default return key on `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`  for `UITextField` when text `length` is <=4?

Can any one help me on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to disable the keyboard or only hide the return key

Comment: Is it Possible to do it?

Comment: Any one please help me

Comment: i think you change the return key but i dont sure not to hide

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this code Snippet:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length <= 4)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

and be sure that you have set the delegate of Textfield to self

```
yourTextFeild.delegate = self;
```

hope this works!!

Comment: he need to disable the return key only

Comment: I want to hide only return key

Comment: any one please help me